# Prayer and it's requirements

Tags: salat, jannah, christianity

After a fair bit of reading including Quranic versus (and correct me if I am wrong) Christians or People of the Book do have every opportunity to enter Heaven as do Muslims however I am a little confused by the prayer part.

Assuming Prayer as we know it today is a requirement of Islam, it wasn't a requirement in its 'current practise method' during Christianity times (again correct me if I am wrong as I have no true confirmed access to the - original - bible).

Since that is the case, how would a Christian enter heaven?  I know that belief in one God, belief that God does not have a child, doing righteous deeds gives Christians this chance of entry but is that enough to exempt them from the current Islamic prayer?

For that matter, if it doesn't exempt them and prayer is required, then ultimately haven't they already passively converted? At which part of belief do they even remain Christians?

Comment: If you are asking about orthodox doctrine, then Christians after the advent of the Prophet do not enter heaven. See [Do modern-day Jews, Sabians and Christians have “nothing to fear or to regret” (Qur'an 5:69)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46121/)

Comment: So far all fatwas I read say that a non-Muslim's prayer even if he does it Muslim-like is not accepted. There are in fact statements that say that the earlier prophets used to pray like Muslims.

Comment: People of previous scripture are responsible to accept Islam only if they were informed and educated about it.  The responsibility for dawa and education of the jahaliye falls on the uma.

Answer (score 2):

> Verse (2:62) Indeed, those who believed and those who were Jews or
>   Christians or Sabeans [before Prophet Muhammad] - those [among them]
>   who believed in Allah and the Last Day and did righteousness - will
>   have their reward with their Lord, and no fear will there be
>   concerning them, nor will they grieve.

See the [Quranic verse](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(2:62:1))

It means, those who past & were on the faith of that time, they will be succeeded.

Now you know the last prophet and last book, so you have to follow it:

> Verse (3:19)Indeed, the religion in the sight of Allah is Islam. And
>   those who were given the Scripture did not differ except after
>   knowledge had come to them - out of jealous animosity between
>   themselves. And whoever disbelieves in the verses of Allah , then
>   indeed, Allah is swift in [taking] account.

See the [Quranic Verse](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(3:19:1))

Nothing is from my side, these are the words of God(Allah), decide yourself.

Comment: I have read these versus however I'm not too sure they answer the question. How does this apply to the ability of a Muslim man being able to marry a non-Muslim women (which he can) - Doesn't that ultimately confirm that non-Muslims have a chance at entering heaven since God allows marriage to them? Or does that mean she must covert first?

Comment: dqnet: You are talking something different than the question. It is not true that a Muslim can marry a Non-Muslim. Ask a separate question, sure I will love to answer that.

Comment: You are right in saying my last post may be taking the question out of original context and I will pursue a different question for the topic of marriage however I'm not entirely convinced with your original answer to my original question. The question is do Christians / People of the Book have an opportunity to enter Heaven and if so is it by the means of conversion -only- or can they still enter based on the fundamental Islamic teaching of the Oneness of God and no Shirk and belief in Mohammed PBUH..?  (meaning will they maybe enter Hell first then finally be allowed to enter heaven?).