# Can everyone who is said to go to hell in any verse be considered/assumed a Kafir?

Tags: surat-al-kafirun

I know that Allah sends Kafirs to hell according to many verses.

1. But can everyone who is said to go to hell according to Islam be considered/assumed to be a Kafir?
2. Also, do non-Kafirs go to hell?

For example there are many verse saying that idolators are destined for hell.

**In some cases some group/category people may be said to be destined for hell and one might not find verses confirming they are kaffirs.**

**In the above case, can it be assumed that all people mentioned to be destined for hell in these verses are kaffirs?**

Comment: All non-muslims are kafir, be they atheist, christian, jew, idolater, or muslim apostate etc. There are many questions on this on the site such as [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/), [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16676/) etc.

Comment: Further not all the people going to hell are kafir, as muslim sinners may be punished in hell for a limited period of time.

Comment: @UmH I have updated the question. It doesn't seem to be a duplicate or have an answer. Please check