# Does a muslim have the duty to convert his neighboring?

Tags: conversion, obligation

As a muslim, is it a sin to keep my religion for myself, or do I necessarily have the duty to influence and convert as many infidels as possible during my entire life?

Comment: Was Abu Talib an infidel?

Comment: @smttsp According to almost all scholars, he was.

Comment: @G.Bach, Nope he wasn't an infidel, he was a disbeliever. Infidel has the meaning of enemy not just disbelief.

Comment: @smttsp I thought he was a mushrik and not a kafir. He believed in Allah but associated partners with Him as did the majority of Quraysh. Also please note we are not confident of what exactly happened on his death bed.. did he accept Islam is  know only to Allah.

Comment: @Ahmed, mushrik and kafir have pretty much the same meaning. However, infidel does not. Infidel is more of a Christian term. I don't think muslims use that term for disbelievers. Abu Talib was a disbeliever yet, I agree with you that we don't know what happened to him in his death bed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How do you know all your neighbors are infidels? People of the book and many many many others are not infidels.

But no you shouldn't just knock on their door and say let's read the Qur'an so you can convert sooner. You should be a nice Muslim and socialize with them following these instructions given by the Prophet:

- You must help him if he asks for your help
- Give him relief if he seeks your relief
- Lend him if he needs a loan
- Do not block his air by raising your building high without his permission
- Do not harass him
- Give him a share when you buy fruits; if you do not, bring what you buy quietly and let not your children take them out to excite the jealousy of his children.
- You must visit (and take care of) him when he is ill
- You must attend his funeral when he dies (and take part in burial arrangements)
- If he commits a sin, prevent it from being known
- Congratulate him if he is met with good fortune Grieve in sympathy if
  a calamity befalls him

Doing the above is among their rights. So you should do that first and foremost. If you socialize then I'm sure they'll figure out you're a Muslim. **If** they were interested and asked you questions about Islam *then* proceed further otherwise just keep socializing as you were.

Comment: link of narration: https://www.zakat.org/en/top-11-rights-neighbors-understanding-muslims-duty-neighbors/

Comment: "People of the book and many many many others are not infidels." This is not true, the scholars are pretty much in consensus that those verses promising Jews and Christians rewards refer to those that lived before Muhammad publicized the Quran. See my answer [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/33573/17702) for relevant references. Jews and Christians after Muhammad are definitely kuffar.

Comment: @G.Bach brother, our scholars must be different.

Comment: Can you cite any scholars who say Jews and Christians after Muhammad are not kuffar?

Comment: @G. Bach Kuffar and infidel are kinda different. Infidel has a negative meaning. Kuffar is more like disbeliever